# How i can reduce the memory usage in following code?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.List; 
class Solution {
    public List<Boolean> kidsWithCandies(int[] candies, int extraCandies) {
        List<Boolean> result = new ArrayList<>();
        int highest = 1;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < candies.length ; i++){
            if(candies[i] > highest)
                highest = candies[i];
        }
        for(int i = 0 ; i < candies.length ; i++){
            result.add((candies[i] + extraCandies) >= highest); 
        }
        
        return result;
    }
}
```

I have to tried solve the problem of kidswith highest candies. above code shows the memory usage of 38.9 MB. How can I further reduce it. Please help me to know how this process works.

Comment: hi effa, may i know what is the usage of the second for loop? it added a full list of boolean to check if the candies at that index after adding extra candies is greater than highest number. how will you use the data in result list afterwards? and may i know which java version you are using?

Comment: Effa please provide problem statement with sample input and output. Also add your full code. It helps everyone in providing you with better answers.

Comment: If you are allowed to change the method return type, try changing it to `boolean[]` instead of `List<Boolean>`

Comment: What is your _purpose_ for reducing memory usage below 39MB? That's already pretty compact for a Java program.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is already enough compact. Only two things you can do:

1. use BitSet
2. use Array in place of the List as you know the size of the array.

### Explanation:

1. `boolean` vs `BitSet`

---

`boolean`

To store and manipulate arrays of bits, one might argue that we should use `boolean[]` as our data structure. At first glance, that might seem a reasonable suggestion.

To make matters more concrete, let's see how much space a boolean[] with 1024 elements consumes:

```
boolean[] bits = new boolean[1024];
System.out.println(ClassLayout.parseInstance(bits).toPrintable());
```

Ideally, we expect a 1024-bit memory footprint from this array. However, the Java Object Layout (JOL) reveals an entirely different reality:

```
[Z object internals:
 OFFSET  SIZE      TYPE DESCRIPTION            VALUE
      0     4           (object header)        01 00 00 00 (00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000) (1)
      4     4           (object header)        00 00 00 00 (00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000) (0)
      8     4           (object header)        7b 12 07 00 (01111011 00010010 00000111 00000000) (463483)
     12     4           (object header)        00 04 00 00 (00000000 00000100 00000000 00000000) (1024)
     16  1024   boolean [Z.                    N/A
Instance size: 1040 bytes
```

If we ignore the overhead of the object header, the array elements are consuming 1024 bytes, instead of the expected 1024 bits. That's 700% more memory than what we expected.

`BitSet`
Let's compare the memory footprint of a BitSet instance with 1024 bits with the boolean[] we saw earlier:

```
BitSet bitSet = new BitSet(1024);

System.out.println(GraphLayout.parseInstance(bitSet).toPrintable());
```

This will print both the shallow size of the BitSet instance and the size of its internal array:

```
java.util.BitSet@75412c2fd object externals:
          ADDRESS       SIZE TYPE             PATH         VALUE
        70f97d208         24 java.util.BitSet              (object)
        70f97d220        144 [J               .words       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

As shown above, it uses a long[] with 16 elements (16 * 64 bits = 1024 bits) internally. Anyway, this instance is using 168 bytes in total, while the boolean[] were using 1024 bytes.

For more details click [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-bitset).

2. `ArrayList` vs `Array`

---

Array memory is allocated on creation. When we initialize an array, it allocates the memory according to the size and type of an array. It initializes all the elements with a null value for reference types and the default value for primitive types.

ArrayList changes memory allocation as it grows. When we specify the capacity while initializing the ArrayList, it allocates `enough memory` to store objects up to that capacity. The logical size remains 0. When it is time to expand the capacity, a new, larger array is created, and the values are copied to it.

So, ArrayList(List) requires more memory consumption than simple Arrays.

For more details click [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-list-capacity-array-size).

---

Modified memory-optimized version:

```
public BitSet kidsWithCandies(int[] candies, int extraCandies) {
    BitSet bitSet = new BitSet(candies.length);
    int highest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
  
    for(int i = 0 ; i < candies.length ; i++){
        if(candies[i] > highest)
            highest = candies[i];
    }
    
    for(int i = 0 ; i < candies.length ; i++){
        bitSet.set(i,(candies[i] + extraCandies) >= highest );
    }
    
    return bitSet;
}
```

Comment: Is this solution reduce your memory usages?

Comment: thank you Md. kawser habib . I solve this problem on leetcode where we are not allowed to change the return type. I get to know some new things, thanks for that.

Comment: https://leetcode.com/problems/kids-with-the-greatest-number-of-candies/  this is the link of the problem.

Comment: You have missed return type point in your question.